# Format namenode in Hadoop: IllegalArgumentException Uri has an authority component

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am trying to install and run `Hadoop` for first time. While formatting the `namenode` I get the following error.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI has an authority component  at
java.io.File.<init>(File.java:423)  at
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NNStorage.getStorageDirectory(NNStorage.java:329)
at
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLog.initJournals(FSEditLog.java:270)
at
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLog.initJournalsForWrite(FSEditLog.java:241)
at
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.format(NameNode.java:938)
at
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1382)
at
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1507)
16/04/12 17:15:35 INFO util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1 16/04/12
17:15:35 INFO namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at
psubuntu-Inspiron-5520/127.0.1.1
************************************************************/**
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems you have not set .xml files properly.
edit files in ~/hadoop/etc/hadoop folder for
core-site.xml ->

```
<!-- core-site.xml -->
<configuration>
<property>
<name>fs.defaultFS</name>
<value>hdfs://localhost/</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

for hdfs-site.xml

```
<!-- hdfs-site.xml -->
<configuration>
<property>
<name>dfs.replication</name>
<value>1</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

for mapred-site.xml

```
 <!-- mapred-site.xml -->
    <configuration>
    <property>
    <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
    <value>yarn</value>
    </property>
    </configuration>
```

for yarn-site.xml

```
<!-- yarn-site.xml -->
<configuration>
<property>
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
<value>localhost</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
<value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```